# Elliptic PDE Integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\zeta\in C_0^1(\Omega)$ and $u>0$ in $\overline{\Omega}$.  Suppose $\lambda|\xi|^2\leq a_{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j\leq\Lambda|\xi|^2$ for $x\in \Omega$ and $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Apparently
$$
\int\frac{\zeta^2}{u^2}a_{ij}D_iuD_ju\leq 2\int\frac{\zeta}{u}a_{ij}D_iuD_j\zeta
$$
implies
$$
\int\zeta^2|D\log u|^2\leq C\int|D\zeta|^2
$$
for some constant dependent on $\Lambda/\lambda$.  However, I fail to see it.  Any hints/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $i = j$. Your first inequality and Holder's inequality lead to
$$ \int \frac{\zeta^2}{u^2} a_{ii} (D_i u)^2 \le 2 \left(\int \frac{\zeta^2}{u^2} a_{ii} (D_i u)^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \int a_{ii} (D_i \zeta)^2 \right)^{1/2}$$
so that
$$ \int \frac{\zeta^2}{u^2} a_{ii} (D_i u)^2 \le 2\int a_{ii} (D_i \zeta)^2.$$

Since $\lambda \le a_{ii}(x) \le \Lambda$ for each $i$ and $D_i \log u = \dfrac{D_i u}{u}$  you get
$$ \lambda \int \zeta^2(D_i \log u)^2 \le 2 \Lambda \int (D_i \zeta)^2.$$
Now sum over $i$.

Comment: One question: does it matter that the first inequality is true when summed over all $i$, $j$? Can we necessarily say that the inequality is true for each $i$, $j$?

Comment: The second inequality is weaker than the first, since a lot of information is being disregarded. I'm not sure about your second question.

Comment: In the first inequality above, I mean
$$
\sum_{i,j}\int\frac{\zeta^2}{u^2}a_{ij}D_iuD_ju\leq\sum_{i,j}\int\frac{\zeta}{u}a_{ij}D_iuD_j\zeta.
$$
Does that necessarily imply
$$
\sum_{i}\int\frac{\zeta^2}{u^2}a_{ii}D_iuD_iu\leq\sum_{i}\int\frac{\zeta}{u}a_{ii}D_iuD_i\zeta\,\,?
$$